# IE change function wont fire

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I got this simple function in jquery/javascript that wont work in IE7, IE8:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']", selector).change(function() {
    recalcTotalPrice(selector);
  });
```

What is the problem with it?

Comment: sorry about my first comment, but this seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vneuC/

Comment: Are you sure that `selector` variable has checboxes?

Comment: Welcome to the glamorous world of Internet Explorer!

Comment: Tried simplifying the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems fine. Here is what I tried: ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/9r8pA/))

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" value="1"> <label for="c1">test</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" value="2"> <label for="c2">test</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c3" value="4"> <label for="c3">test</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c4" value="8"> <label for="c4">test</label>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function recalcTotalPrice(s) {
    var total = 0;
    s.find(':checked').each(function() {
        total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });
    $('#result').html(total);
}

var selector = $('form');
$("input[type='checkbox']", selector).change(function() {
    recalcTotalPrice(selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience observing changes of the state of check boxes is more reliably done with the `click` event than with `change`.